# I am looking to make a switch statement to add a different page depending on which button the user presses

Tags: java, swing, button, switch-statement, jbutton

```
private Component createContent() {
        final Image image = requestImage();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (String label : new String[]{"BlackJack", "Poker", "Go-Fish"}) {
            JButton button = new JButton(label);
            button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 15)));
            panel.add(button);
        }

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        return panel;
    }
```

This is the example im using. I have the rest of the code just displays the window and background image. I am trying to which the image and buttons and button placement when the user clicks on a button.

Comment: *"..the rest of the code.."* Good that you did not dump the entire code, but.. 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: BTW 1) `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`, as **every** `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver`. 2) `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to add some Action Listeners to your buttons that call the method they trigger.

`button.addActionListener(listener)`

Being the listener object an implementation of the ActionListener interface (You must define de actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) method)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

Remember that a switch statement in Java could only function with primitives and since JDK 7 String literals, but thats it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**A.** Let the class, where you have written this method, implement `ActionListener`

**B.** Add the `ActionListener` to each button as follows:

```
for (String label : new String[]{"BlackJack", "Poker", "Go-Fish"}) {
    JButton button = new JButton(label);
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 15)));
    panel.add(button);
}
```

**C.** Define the following method in this class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
    case "BlackJack":
        // TODO
        break;

    case "Poker":
        // TODO
        break;
    case "Go-Fish":
        // TODO
        break;
    }
}
```